# Running mono/c# on intel phi coprocessor

Tags: c#, linux, mono, intel

Is it possible to run mono on intel's phi coprocessors? From what i have understood they are operating a form of Linux but i haven't managed to find a concrete answer. If it is possible, are there any sort of limitations/issues? I'm looking to run some C# code on them as i had heard there are no issues with warp divergence, or something similar.

Comment: Hans, did you get it to work?

Comment: No i decided to pursue a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely possible to run mono on Phi due to the fact that it is just running a standard Linux kernel. Any specific shared libraries you need would also have to be compiled for mic and copied to the card as well.

Comment: can you use openMP on mono code? What's the tool chain? Or do you mean that you could run mono on the linux side of the phi but not actually use any of the other cores? Even gcc itself is particular about MIC code generation, from what I've read.