# How to program Intel Xeon Phi with C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xeon-phi

I am a C# programmer with some C++ experience, all on Windows.

With this skill set, are there any options to develop for Intel Xeon Phi processor?

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999449/running-mono-c-on-intel-phi-coprocessor), but not sure if that's the best/only way.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Nice enthusiasm! What do you want to develop for which you need help here?

Comment: Financial computations and modelling.

Comment: Your question needs a blog post.

Comment: This question is off-topic (questions asking for resources are not suitable for SO), primarily opinion based, and too broad.

Comment: try this site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AustinHenley Is off-topic also true if we add that you can hardly find any information about it using big search engines? I don't think there will be a religion war here, given that there are hardly any to find.

Comment: @CsabaToth  I found my answer using google :P

Comment: I think theOP is asking whether it's possible to run .NET on a Xeon Phi card. Pity that too many readers misunderstood the question and chose to close it.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [An Overview of Programming for Intel® Xeon® processors and Intel® Xeon Phi coprocessors](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/330164/an-overview-of-programming-for-intel-xeon-processors-and-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessors.pdf) for well .. an overview.

From the section:

**Compiler and programming models**

> There are some recommendations we can make based on what has been working well for developers. For Fortran programmers, use OpenMP, DO CONCURRENT and MPI. For C++ programmers, use Intel TBB, Intel Cilk Plus and OpenMP. For C programmers, use OpenMP and Intel Cilk Plus.

Also from the same source:

**Additional reading**

> > Additional material regarding programming for Intel Xeon Phi coprocessors can be found at http://intel.com/software/mic.
> >
> > A new book titled “Intel® Xeon PhiTM Coprocessor High Performance Programming, Volume 1: Essentials” by Jim Jeffers and James Reinders, © 2013, published by Intel Press, is expected to be available in early 2013.